# Remove caching in Android using PhoneGap

Tags: android, cordova

I want to remove caching in Android. I am using PhoneGap technology. Actually everything is working fine in Blackberry or iOS, but there is problem in Android. In my app, there is an auto suggested list of station names. When the user selects station for the first time, it is fine, but when the user selects the same station next time, it shows the station name in big font (white background (single list different from my original station list), which I think is due to caching).

I think this is due to Android using Chrome. Would you please suggest me how to remove this caching?

```
<input id="getStationDesc" name="getStationDesc" type="text" class="log_txtfield" disabled="disabled"/>
<script>
    var obj = actb(document.getElementById('getStationDesc'),stationList);
    //setTimeout(function(){obj.actb_keywords = custom2;},10000);
    this.actb_timeOut = -1;
    // Number of elements autocomplete can show (-1: no limit)
    this.actb_lim = 10;
    // should the auto complete be limited to the beginning of keyword?
    this.actb_firstText = true;
    // Enable Mouse Support
    this.actb_mouse = true;
    // Delimiter for multiple autocomplete.
    // Set it to empty array for single autocomplete
    this.actb_delimiter = new Array(' ',',');
    // Show widget only after this number of characters is typed in.
    this.actb_startcheck = 1;

    this.actb_bgColor = '#dbe3ec';
    this.actb_textColor = '#00256a';
    this.actb_hColor = '#dbe3ec';
    this.actb_fFamily = 'arial';
    this.actb_fSize = '16px';   
    this.actb_hStyle = 'text-decoration:underline;font-weight="bold";text-align="left"';
    function FillValues()
    {
        document.getElementById('getStationCode').value = document.getElementById('getStationDesc').value.substring(0,3);               
    }
</script>
```

Comment: i.stack.imgur.com/mT8eg.jpg[^]  this my issue. please help why this white screen come

Comment: On a related not: I needed to clear the image cache when writing a Phonegap app. Since these are loaded by the browser, it maintains the cache outside of your app, so I didn't need to bother how many remote images my HTML had loaded. I left it to the browser to decide how to expire them.

Answer (score 1):

You can clear cache manually in Phonegap. I used to remove cache memory of the application every time, before the application loads. Try this code,

```
super.clearCache();
super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
```

If you want, you can use in the application ending also.

UPDATED: Another solution,

after your actb() function, call the page create,

```
$("#index").trigger("pagecreate");
/*#index is the id of the page*/
```

Comment: I think this code is  used when application is launch first or launch  other time and remove caching in loading time.I want to ask one question is this code remove caching  when user switch the screens and come to index.html? that time caching is removed ?

Comment: okay.. then its not be a cache problem. The problem is the list style not applied properly when you dynamically changing the list view in the second time of list selection. Whenever you come back to the same list view, just refresh the list.

Comment: refresh or recreate the auto suggestion list.

Comment: i used this code but unable to remove caching can you please help me.http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8020/Auto-complete-Control