# Remove caching in android using phone gap technology

Tags: android, cordova

In my app there might be a problem of caching or something else in android  and i don't know how to remove this problem ![enter image description here][1]. actually  first i download list from server , but when i select one station from list it fine, but when i select same station it show like this.

Comment: your image is not uploaded edit your question

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/mT8eg.jpg[^]

Comment: Duplicate question by same user http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12224076/remove-caching-in-android-using-phonegap/12225510#12225510

Comment: actually that solution doesn't work . please help.